# Traffic segmentation for a particular subnet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn

Two questions is it possible to segment traffic for a particular subnet to use an interface and at the same time receive traffic from a different subnet via the same interface?

This is the scenario. Sitting at home on my laptop I want to vpn into my office to be able to connect to the servers there using wlan0 but without adding another interface I also want all the rest of my traffic to use wlan0 to connect to the internet instead of routing it to the office first.  Is this possible? If so w

Comment: Check whether your VPN software supports [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, some numbers will help to give you a clearer answer. In my case i rewrite my routing table based on me needs.

Comment: Sure, you can easily run multiple subnets on an interface—just use `ip addr add` to add another IP (on a different subnet) to it. But that doesn't sound like it answers your actual question; which VPN program is this? How does it set up routing?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Rabin Sure. My home network has a wireless gateway on a 192.168.25.x subnet, I vpn to the office using NetworkManager, I then receive a ppp0 ip in the 192.168.2.x subnet. Ideally all traffic that routes to 2.x domains and 69.90.218.x domains would all be routed through the ppp0 domain. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @derobert I use NetworkManager to set up the vpn. I can then connect using the command 
    nmcli con up id Work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your shell as root,

```
# This will set the routing table to use the ppp0 interface for 
#  192.168.2.0/24 and 69.90.218.0/24 networks
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev ppp0
ip route add 69.90.218.0/24 dev ppp0
```

For every thing else (0.0.0.0) your default route should be your home GW

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.25.1 dev wlan0  proto static  metric 1024 
192.168.25.0/24 dev em1   proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.25.10 
192.168.2.0/24 dev  ppp0  proto static  scope link  metric 1024 
192.168.2.0/24 dev  ppp0  proto static  scope link  metric 1024
```

where:

- ***192.168.25.10*** is your wlan home ip address
- ***192.168.25.1*** is you home gateway address (your router)

If your are using Network-Manager you can set this setting in the ppp0 connection settings.